# Share reCAPTCHA settings page with other team members

Tags: recaptcha

I've added reCAPTCHA to a client's website. Easy enough. Works well enough too.

But the settings etc. here...

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#site/?setup

... are only available to my Google account.

Does anyone know how share access to this with other members of the team here?

Obviously I've asked on the Google Group for it, but got no response so far.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Giving another developer access to the reCAPTCHA settings for your page is as easy as adding them to the *Owners* in the *Key Settings* dialog of the admin panel:

[image]

After doing so, they will be able to access and change the settings via https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin, just as you are.

Comment: You don't need to feel stupid. I think those settings are hard to find... especially if you are searching for an section in your main-google-account settings to create those Sub-Accounts. I also was searching a long time to find only this posting here... and be glad that someone figured out how to do this. Nevertheless, a global section to setup SubAccounts for Google-Services would be nice!

Comment: I also missed this. It's completely different from how you administer access to your firebase project and other google related consoles. I usually create projects from my google project root account and immediately share access with my individual developers (and my personal account), then keep the root google account credentials stored safely not to be used unless necessary - and the fact that I didn't manage to delegate admin of reCAPTCHA settings was a big issue.